# Is the usage 'the message didn't send' grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, idioms, word-usage

I have often encountered this sentence on Facebook; even a web-search of this string indicates that it is used quite commonly. However, is it correct to say so? 
The dictionary definitions of the word `send` do not seem to be consistent with this usage.

Comment: It's a usage that is becoming increasingly common. It's an ergative usage, in this particular case often restricted to the negative: _I sent the message / the message didn't send._ Compare _I cooked the turkey slowly / the turkey cooked slowly._ 'The dictionary definitions' is imprecise and potentially misleading. Have you checked in OED?

Comment: This is generally deemed the middle voice.

Comment: I have seen at least one article reserving the term 'middle voice' for stative usages. Thus **middle voice**: The Shrunk and Write Grammar sold for $30 back then. / **Ergative usage** the book sold within minutes (punctive). Normally, ice melts at 0 Celsius. / The ice cube quickly melted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the middle construction. It's quite common with any number of other verbs ("the door wouldn't shut", "the letter wasn't printing", "the socks didn't wash", "this car just won't sell"), and is not limited to English to boot.

Most importantly, quite often, though not always, it conveys something different from both active and passive. That is actually the case here.

In the active "X didn't send the message", you put the blame squarely on the sender. The passive "the message hasn't been sent" softens it up, but it's still clearly someone's fault. In "the message didn't send" you only really blame the message itself, or perhaps the cosmic karma.

Comment: Debate over middle usage / ergative usage aside, have you any authority licensing this usage of 'send' (lack of which is the reason I refrained from submitting an 'answer'?)

Comment: @Edwin - It might be hard to find prior examples, because this seems like a usage more fitting for e-communication. _The message didn't send_ passes my ear test when talking about a text message or an email message, but I don't think I'd say, "The package didn't send" when talking about a cardboard box and a traditional postal system.

Comment: @J.R. I quite agree with all you say. It certainly passes my ear test, and I agree that one has to be careful about claiming exactly what subjects are acceptable. The snag is that even dictionaries don't agree on many things, and posting according to ear test assessment is far more subjective.

Comment: @Edwin: yes, you are of course right, it would be great to see an authority back me (and you, and J.R.) up that this emerging "the message is sending" is indeed English and not some kind of pidgin. But the operational word here is "emerging", so it's one of those edge cases where the whole point of ELU is to step in and *be* that authority *itself*. To put it another way: if every question can be answered by checking CGEL or OED, what is even the purpose of this site here at all?

Comment: I'd not argue about the sentiment behind your final sentence; far from it. But not all verbs are normally used in middle / ergative constructions. This book sells well // ?/*This caravan hires well. I'd expect an answer to address the issue of acceptability in a given case.

Comment: @J.R. I agree, and I think the reason is because in e-communication there is a host of nebulous middle men that could be to blame. It could be the email app, it could be your internet connection, the server, etc. Baring truly extraordinary circumstances, if a package doesn't get sent it's either because of you or the postman.

Answer (score 0):

AmE,(especially where I live, in NY) is an extremely flexible entity. Since the main purpose of language is to communicate, as long as the meaning is clear, most people accept oddities like "The message didn't send." There  are many cultures in this area and most have a certain characteristic flavor to the way they speak English. There are also many differences within the generations of native speakers. After a while one's ear becomes trained to understand the different *dialects*, if you will.

That being said, there are still certain forums where one would not want to "show your a**", as my husband says. If is is necessary to conceal one's youth/origin (in a formal document, for example) it might be preferable to say, "It appears that the email message was not transmitted/received."

Answer (score -2):

Jamal 
I think the verb send is a transitive verb that needs to be followed by an object which dose not exist in this sentence , so its not a good one